# Anchor tag not showing up in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm building out a frontend site and I cannot figure out why my anchor tag is not being displayed in IE 11. I'm not doing anything fancy to it, it's just not visible.

The site is live at etcnow.org

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<section class="curriculum centered-block">
    <h3>Curriculum</h3>
    <p>
        ETC’s integrative and alternative education model is designed to
        eliminate the stigma of utilizing mental health services. Its seamless
        clinical learning model fosters emotional self-efficacy while building
        essential life skills.
    </p>
    <a class="btn grow" href="/curriculum">Learn More</a>
</section>
```

Comment: My guess (though could be wrong) is your use of `calc` and `vw` in the section padding? I don't have IE to test on though, so not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE cant handle the CSS variable for the background-color. Use a fallback such as `background-color: green` and browsers that dont support CSS variables will use the fallback instead.
[image]

```
.btn {
    background-color: green;
    background-color: var(--green, green);
}
```

Comment: if you want to use variable, I recommend this solution converts variable into normal data understandable for IE [postcss-css-variables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-css-variables) Of course, if you don't need these variables, e.g. js
I use this solution here [lazy-youtube](https://github.com/tomik23/lazy-youtube/blob/master/postcss.config.js#L7)